# Will the journal show when I overtake gyms?

Tags: pokemon-go

My friends and I are trying to organise a Pokewalk in our college, and we need to ensure that no one takes over the gyms (as gym battles will be the second round in that contest). We thought we could use the journal of the game to check whether they have taken over the gyms in the past 48 hours, (2nd round happens after at least 48 hours of the Pokewalk). Will our plan work?

Answer (score 1):

No. I've tested this before and it doesn't show up, at all.

Comment: Same here. Took 2 gyms and when I lost it hours later I did not get any new journal entries.